# Select de la columna no multiplica el valor por un número dado

Tags: sqlite3

Tengo una consulta sql en la que quiero multiplicar una columna, pero haga lo que haga, siempre muestra el mismo valor. Lo describo:

```
SELECT column1, column2, column3*5, ID FROM (aquí pongo una consulta sql con 4 uniones) WHERE Column1 <> '-';
```

Devuelve una fila, lo cual es correcto, pero nunca multiplica column3 por 5

¿Alguien entiende lo que está pasando?

Hago lo mismo con una consulta sql sin ninguna unión y funciona bien.

Nota esto es la consulta real pero no con columnas reales:

```
SELECT Columna1, Columna2, Columna3 Columna3, Columna4, ID FROM 
(
SELECT tabla1.Nombre AS Columna1, tabla2.Columna2 AS Columna2, tabla2.Columna3 AS Columna3, SUM([m_tabla2].Columna4) Columna4, tabla2.ID as ID FROM tabla2 INNER JOIN tabla1 ON tabla2.IDColumna1 = tabla1.ID INNER JOIN [m_tabla2] ON tabla2.ID=[m_tabla2].ColumnaData5 WHERE ColumnaData1 = 28 AND [m_tabla2].ColumnaData3 = '-' AND ColumnaData2=0 AND ColumnaData4 = 0 AND (Columna3 <> '-' AND Strftime('%Y', tabla2.Columna3) = '2023') GROUP BY tabla2.ID 
UNION 
SELECT tabla1.Nombre AS Columna1, tabla2.Columna2 AS Columna2, tabla2.Columna3 AS Columna3, SUM([m_tabla2].Columna4) Columna4, tabla2.ID as ID FROM tabla2 INNER JOIN tabla1 ON tabla2.IDColumna1 = tabla1.ID INNER JOIN [m_tabla2] ON tabla2.ID=[m_tabla2].ColumnaData5 WHERE ColumnaData1 = 28 AND [m_tabla2].ColumnaData3 = '-' AND ColumnaData2=0 AND ColumnaData4 = 0 AND Strftime('%Y', tabla2.Columna2) = '2023' AND (Columna3 = '-' AND Columna2 > '2023-03-19')  GROUP BY tabla2.ID 
UNION 
SELECT tabla1.Nombre AS Columna1, tabla2.Columna2 AS Columna2, tabla2.Columna3 AS Columna3, SUM([m_tabla2].CuantoD) as Columna4, tabla2.ID as ID FROM tabla2 INNER JOIN tabla1 ON tabla2.IDColumna1 = tabla1.ID INNER JOIN [m_tabla2] ON tabla2.ID=[m_tabla2].ColumnaData5 WHERE idCuentaD = 28 AND [m_tabla2].ColumnaData3 = '-' AND ColumnaData2=0 AND ColumnaData4 = 0 AND Strftime('%Y', tabla2.Columna2) = '2023' GROUP BY tabla2.ID 
UNION 
SELECT Tarjetas.Nombre AS Columna1, tabla2.Columna2 AS Columna2, tabla2.Columna3 AS Columna3, SUM([m_tabla2].Cuanto) AS Columna4, 0 AS ID FROM tabla2 INNER JOIN tabla1 ON tabla2.IDColumna1 = tabla1.ID INNER JOIN Tarjetas ON tabla2.ColumnaData4 = Tarjetas.ID INNER JOIN [m_tabla2] ON tabla2.ID=[m_tabla2].ColumnaData5 WHERE ColumnaData1 = 28 AND [m_tabla2].ColumnaData3 = '-' AND ColumnaData2=0 AND Strftime('%Y', tabla2.Columna2) = '2023' GROUP BY Columna1, Columna2, Columna3 ORDER BY tabla2.Columna2 DESC) WHERE Columna3 = '-' 
UNION ALL 
SELECT Columna1, Columna2, Columna3 Columna3, Columna4, ID FROM (SELECT tabla1.Nombre AS Columna1, tabla2.Columna2 AS Columna2, tabla2.Columna3 AS Columna3, SUM([m_tabla2].Cuanto) Columna4, tabla2.ID as ID FROM tabla2 INNER JOIN tabla1 ON tabla2.IDColumna1 = tabla1.ID INNER JOIN [m_tabla2] ON tabla2.ID=[m_tabla2].ColumnaData5 WHERE ColumnaData1 = 28 AND [m_tabla2].ColumnaData3 = '-' AND ColumnaData2=0 AND ColumnaData4 = 0 AND (Columna3 <> '-' AND Strftime('%Y', tabla2.Columna3) = '2023') GROUP BY tabla2.ID 
UNION 
SELECT tabla1.Nombre AS Columna1, tabla2.Columna2 AS Columna2, tabla2.Columna3 AS Columna3, SUM([m_tabla2].Cuanto) Columna4, tabla2.ID as ID FROM tabla2 INNER JOIN tabla1 ON tabla2.IDColumna1 = tabla1.ID INNER JOIN [m_tabla2] ON tabla2.ID=[m_tabla2].ColumnaData5 WHERE ColumnaData1 = 28 AND [m_tabla2].ColumnaData3 = '-' AND ColumnaData2=0 AND ColumnaData4 = 0 AND Strftime('%Y', tabla2.Columna2) = '2023' AND (Columna3 = '-' AND Columna2 > '2023-03-19')  GROUP BY tabla2.ID 
UNION 
SELECT tabla1.Nombre AS Columna1, tabla2.Columna2 AS Columna2, tabla2.Columna3 AS Columna3, SUM([m_tabla2].CuantoD) as Columna4, tabla2.ID as ID FROM tabla2 INNER JOIN tabla1 ON tabla2.IDColumna1 = tabla1.ID INNER JOIN [m_tabla2] ON tabla2.ID=[m_tabla2].ColumnaData5 WHERE idCuentaD = 28 AND [m_tabla2].ColumnaData3 = '-' AND ColumnaData2=0 AND ColumnaData4 = 0 AND Strftime('%Y', tabla2.Columna2) = '2023' GROUP BY tabla2.ID 
UNION 
SELECT Tarjetas.Nombre AS Columna1, tabla2.Columna2 AS Columna2, tabla2.Columna3 AS Columna3, SUM([m_tabla2].Cuanto) AS Columna4, 0 AS ID FROM tabla2 INNER JOIN tabla1 ON tabla2.IDColumna1 = tabla1.ID INNER JOIN Tarjetas ON tabla2.ColumnaData4 = Tarjetas.ID INNER JOIN [m_tabla2] ON tabla2.ID=[m_tabla2].ColumnaData5 WHERE ColumnaData1 = 28 AND [m_tabla2].ColumnaData3 = '-' AND ColumnaData2=0 AND Strftime('%Y', tabla2.Columna2) = '2023' GROUP BY Columna1, Columna2, Columna3  ORDER BY tabla2.Columna3 DESC, ID DESC
) 

WHERE Columna3 <> '-';
```

Comment: ¿Y que devuelve? ¿Tienes un error? ¿Revisaste que la columna sea numérica?

Comment: Devuelve la fila correctamente con el valor de la columna3 que es float y además el valor es el esperado. Pero nunca lo devuelve con la Multiplicación, solo devuelve el valor esperado y si miramos el nombre de la columna, se llama columna3*5

Comment: Quiero añadir que el valor numerico que devuelve columna3 es igual que columna3*5, y si pongo columna3*10 devuelve lo mismo tambien como columna3. Por si os da mas pista esta información. Por otra parte si el cambio de *5 se lo pongo a cada columna3 dentro de los Union, entonces sale el resultado que yo deseo con el calculo correcto.

Comment: Si los `unions` no forman parte de una subconsulta tienes que hacer la multiplicación en cada select, si los tienes dentro de una subconsulta, ejemplo `FROM (select * ... union select * ...)` debería funcionar hacer la multiplicación en la consulta principal.

Comment: Pues lo tengo tal que así, como tu dices: ejemplo FROM (select * ... union select * ...) pero no funciona. Digamos que si no multiplico la columna3 da el mismo resultado que si le pongo a la columna3*5, da el mismo número.

Comment: He puesto la consulta por que para mi es un misterio que quería compartir con algún experto. gracias.

Comment: No me queda claro cual es el comportamiento malo, sobre todo después de leer los comentarios. Sugiero que agregues a la pregunta los valores que estás obteniendo y los que esperas obtener, además, de ser posible que simplifiques el problema (un [mcve] sería lo ideal).

Comment: Lo estudio lo que me propones pero no prometo que me falle al simplificarlo todo, esto lo he hecho para mi mismo y funcionó todo perfectamente. Pero seguiré con otra consulta para compartirla con ustedes. Gracias.

Comment: Por lo menos, incluye los datos. Puedes también agregar a tu consulta la columna sin ninguna operación, digamos ```select columna3, columna3*5 bla, bla```, debiera devolver, por decir, ```5, 15, bla```, y no ```5, 5, bla```.

Comment: Acabo ver el problema y ya se la solución. Si miran la consulta con detenimiento, yo hice en el pasado una unión de dos consultas donde cada una eran también consultas UNION, Pues yo solo ponía el multiplicador en la columna de una de las dos consultas y para colmo la colocaba en la consulta que no devolvía ningún resultado, por lo tanto siempre me daba el resultado x con multiplicador, divisor o cualquier operación. La solución es poner el multiplicador en ambas consultas y listo, funciona perfectamente. Mil disculpas, debería haberlo analizado con la consulta formateada y lo hubiera visto.

Answer (score 0):

Solución. Si miran la consulta con detenimiento, yo hice en el pasado una consulta con un UNION ALL por lo que existe dos consultas unidas. Ambas consultas deben de llevar la columna con su multiplicador sino no funciona el valor que deseo multiplicar con la columna.